# Embedd JSON from search in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, search

I have a search which responds with json. What I want is, that the JSON is included in my HTML and not shown in the browser

When I go to my website www.XXX.com/search/keyword, it will respond with this json:

```
{
"items": [{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "cool name",
    "title": "title of the object",
    "vendor": "vendor name"
}
```

and so on (just an example)

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form name="test" action="/" id="form"/>
  <input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="search">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Then I read the value from the form and include this in my action with JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $action = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
  document.getElementById("form").action = 'www.XXX.com/search/' + $action;
</script>
```

But now it shows me the JSON in my browser. What I want is to include the JSON in my HTML and show the values.
How can I take the JSON from www.XXX.com/search/keyword and list it in my view?

Best regards and thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an AJAX request to solve this task. 
This means that you have to asynchronously submit the form and when the request completes, it gives you a response and you have to insert it somewhere in your page.

I don't know what requirement you have, but using JQUERY framework you could do something like this:

```
$.getJSON('www.XXX.com/search/'+ document.getElementById("keyword").value, function(data){
//data is your JSON that you receive
document.getElementById("Id_of_where_to_insert_in_html").innerHtml(data);

//Or you can do something with the data, like parsing , building html dinamically etc.
});
```

Moreover, you cand use JQUERY-UI with Autocomplete Widget to get sugestions when writing in the keyword text field